# Problem after upgrade to ubuntu 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

I was upgrading ubuntu to 21.10 on my raspberry pi 4b (8gb). and in the middle of the process suddenly the power went out.
After that power backs, and turning on the raspberry, it doesn't work properly.

After 4 or 5 minutes suddenly the mouse cursor stop working and nothing works anymore.
Also in that 4 or 5 minutes, it works really slowly.

I tried software upgrade, apt-get update/upgrade. But they weren't useful.

What should I do now to fix this problem?

Comment: If the pi was writing at the time power went out your SD media maybe damaged. I'd likely run `badblocks` on it (in a normal PC) & replace the media (ssd's & hdd's are designed to cope with ports being bad; consumable media is made to cost and is just replaced)

Comment: Format the card and fresh install 21.10. It is the simplest solution.

Comment: Is there any other way? Like downgrading to ubunto 20 or do sth to fix the problems of installation sth like that. Because there was a lot of information application that take a lot to redo from 0.   IN ADDITION, as i remember for upgrading there was about 7 or 8 steps wich when the power went out there was just 2 or 3 to be done and one of them was clearing some datas. I dont remember those well i tought maybe it could help to do those steps now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about raspberry pi, but I'll give you an idea that it worked for me:

How it is very difficult to know which file is corrupt and obviously when reinstalling Ubuntu would lose all the configuration, in Synaptic I marked all the packages to reinstall.  After the process I restarted and it was like new.

Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

A power loss during a release-upgrade is just about the worst thing that can happen to your system, since that is the time that your system is most vulnerable to damage.

You will have two inconsistent and incomplete sets of packages, so failure-to-boot or unexpected behavior is very possible.

Repair depends upon exactly which package was being overwritten when the power loss occurred:

- If a non-critical package, the system can sometimes be recovered by running a normal apt upgrade.
- If critical package, then the system cannot be easily recovered (that's what makes it critical) by an unskilled user.

**For most users, the easiest and fastest solution is to back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu.**

For curious experimenters, you can remove the SD Card/HDD/SSD and plug it into a working system, repair the filesystem damage, and complete the release-upgrade. The basic sequence is to run fsck to repair the damaged filesystem, chroot into the newly-repaired filesystem, have apt repeat/complete the dist-upgrade, have apt autoremove the orphans, and then have snapd refresh the snaps.